# How to send an array from React Application to Flask Application

Tags: reactjs, post, flask, get

I've been trying to send a simple array from my React app to my Flask app but I'm pretty new to application networks.

Flask (entire application):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request():
    data = request.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Going to localhost:5000 when both apps are running I get:

```
 Internal Server Error
 The server encountered an internal error and was unable to 
 complete 
 your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error 
 in the application.
```

React:

```
sendTopArtists() {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body:  JSON.stringify(artistList)
  })
  .then(function(response){ 
   return response.json();   
   })
   .then(function(artistList){ 
   console.log(artistList)
   });
}
```

How do I send an array from my React app running on localhost:3000 to my Flask app running on localhost:5000?

Thanks!

Comment: as a side note, make your api requests more specific. `/api/artists` for instance would be a more specific RESTful api route to POST to for creating an `artist` resource. For your issue, you need to return the data from the backend side to the client side. Usually that would be after creating a record in the DB or whatever your use case is, you would return a successful response.

Comment: On your index route `/` you need to `return` something (such as a template or a string or `jsonify` etc). In your Flask code you need to handle HTML requests appropriately using `if request.method == "POST"` and `if request.method == "GET"` or just `else`

Comment: As an addendum, if you're expecting to receive JSON data, you could instead write `request.get_json()` instead of `request.data`